# How to update Lead Status pick value field based on time

Tags: trigger

I have a Lead and two fields:
"Lead status" (datatype: pick value, two values "test1" and "test2")
"Event Date" (datatype: date)

E.g.
Current date is 4/6/2019.

A lead has "Lead status" set to "test1" and "Event Date" set to "4/6/2019".

On 4/7/2019 01:00AM somehow automatically, I need to check all leads that have "Lead status" set to "test1" and "Event Date" set to "current date" - 1 DAY
then
update all of the leads by setting "Lead status" to "test2"

What would be the best way to do this automatically?
I tried to do this by using Process Builder but PB triggers only when lead is edited or created.

Thanks, A

Comment: this should be doable w/ time-based workflows or scheduled actions in PB

Answer (score 0):

You can create Apex Scheduled Job [0][1] to get trigged at 1 AM, query all leads that you want to update and update them.

From Scheduled Class you can start a Queueable Job or Batch job (if you have lots of records to process) and process them.

[0] https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_scheduled

[1] https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm